# setStyleSheet fixates font, no longer updates for font propagation

Tags: c++, qt

If I call `setStyleSheet` on a widget (in this case a `QToolButton`) it no longer updates its font via font propagation from its parent.  That is, once the style sheet is set, a call to setFont on some parent widget will no longer alter the font on this widget.

Is this some way to workaround this broken behaviour?

Note: my stylesheet has no font properties specified, thus according to the docs it shouldn't interfere with the font. (For example: `":checked { border: 1px inset rgba(128,0,0,128); \nbackground-color: rgba( 200, 200, 0, 128 ); }"`)

Note: I'm also reasonably certain I'm setting the font correctly since all other controls in the application update correctly, only those which have a style-sheet set do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the docu on `setFont` says

> Note: If Qt Style Sheets are used on the same widget as setFont(), style sheets will take precedence if the settings conflict.

Which in this case should not play a role, internal qt docu in `setFont` function says

> ### Stylesheet has a different font propagation mechanism. When a stylesheet
>           is applied, fonts are not propagated anymore

So at the end of the day I would always set the parent font first and than apply stylesheets to children

Comment: I do that during startup of course, but our users can change the font at runtime -- which when we get the problem.  Thanks for the reference from the internal docs.